# How to run included tests on deployed pylons application

Tags: python, unit-testing, pylons, nose, paster

I have installed pylons based application from egg, so it sits somewhere under /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages. I see that the tests are packaged too and I would like to run them (to catch a problem that shows up on deployed application but not on development version).

So how do I run them? Doing "nosetests" from directory containing only test.ini and development.ini gives an error about nonexistent test.ini under site-packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from [the horse's mouth](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Unit+Testing):

Install nose: easy_install -W nose.

Run nose: nosetests --with-pylons=test.ini OR python setup.py nosetests

To run "python setup.py nosetests" you need to have a [nosetests] block in your setup.cfg looking like this:

> [nosetests]
>
> verbose=True
>
> verbosity=2
>
> with-pylons=test.ini
>
> detailed-errors=1
>
> with-doctest=True

Comment: I finally put this advice to work and discovered another thing: nosetests need to be run with --exe option, because it would otherwise ignore executable files, and files packaged with "python setup.py bdist_egg" have +x for some reason. So the command line looks like this for me: "nosetests --exe --with-pylons=test.ini mypackage.tests"